# Cython wrapping operator<< from multiple namespaces

Tags: c++, wrapper, iostream, cython, friend

How can I wrap the operator >> overload in Cython?

```
//LIB.h
namespace LIB
{
    class Point
    {
        friend std::istream &operator >> (std::istream &in, Point &pt)
        bool operator == (const Point &pos) const
        ...
    }
}
```

There is already a namespace declared `namespace "LIB":`, so how do I deal with the std:: namespace?

```
#LIB.pxd
cdef extern from "LIB.h" namespace "LIB":
    cdef cppclass Point:
        #friend std::istream &operator >> (std::istream &in, Point &pt)
        bint operator == (const Point &pos) const
        ...
```

[Here it explains](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/SZmOVFSivCA) that multiple cdef extern blocks are possible, but I don't see how that will work since I cannot redefine the class.

Comment: The namespace problem isn't clear at all. In the .h file (`LIB.h` ?), is the operator declared in the namespace `LIB` ? What's the role of `std::` here ? What do you mean by 'There is already a namespace declared' ?

Comment: _Edited for more clarity._ What I am unsure about is how to deal with the second `std::` namespace. All the examples from the cython docs have all the wrapped functions in the same namespace.

Comment: I implemented your edit suggestion on my answer but I also removed all the template parameter to Point to your question since they don't make that much sense and are completely irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to pretend to Cython that `operator<<` is a method of `std::istream` forgetting about the friend stuff. The C++ compiler will then sort out the pieces. So here is what seems to be a working solution (it compiles but I didn't went all the way to test it):

Here is my `LIB.h` wrapped file:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace LIB {
    class Point {
        friend std::istream &operator << (std::istream &in, Point);
    };
}
```

And the Cython wrapper should be as follows:

```
cdef extern from "LIB.h" namespace "LIB":
    cdef cppclass Point:
        pass

cdef extern from "<iostream>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass istream:
        istream &operator << (Point)

    istream cin
```

Then the following file is accepted by the compiler:

```
cimport lib

def foo():
    cdef lib.Point bla

    lib.cin << bla
```

FYI, I compiled with:

```
cython --cplus bla.pyx                  
g++ `python-config --cflags` bla.cpp -c
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that it was possible to start multiple cdef externs in the same .pxd and use them to handle multiple namespaces.